# Use AMPscript to split field at semicolon

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

How do I use AMPscript to split a field at a semicolon and return each part separately?

Example: FirstName;LastName

(note, there are no spaces before or after the semicolon)

I've started (unsuccessfully) to isolate the portion in front of the semicolon, but I also need the portion after the semicolon.

```
%%[

var @full_name, @first_name

set @full_name = AttributeValue("Full Name")

if indexOf(@full_name, ";") > 0 then

set @first_name = substring(@full_name,1,subtract(indexOf(@full_name,";"),1))

endif

]%%
```

_

```
First Name: %%=v(@first_name)=%%

Last Name: %%=v(@last_name)=%%
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on the right track. [Substring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Substring.htm) and [IndexOf](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/IndexOf.htm) can be used to achieve your goal.

```
%%[
VAR @full_name, @first_name, @last_name
SET @full_name = "Joe;Bloggs"

IF IndexOf(@full_name, ";") > 0 THEN
    SET @first_name = Substring(@full_name,1,Subtract(IndexOf(@full_name,";"),1))
    SET @last_name = Substring(@full_name,Add(IndexOf(@full_name,";"),1))
ENDIF

]%%

First Name: %%=v(@first_name)=%%
Last Name: %%=v(@last_name)=%%
```

Output:

```
First Name: Joe
Last Name: Bloggs
```

Alternatively you could use [BuildRowSetFromString](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/buildrowsetfromstring.htm) with [Row](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/row.htm) and [Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/field.htm) like so:

```
%%[

VAR @full_name, @first_name, @last_name, @rs
SET @full_name = "Joe;Bloggs"

IF IndexOf(@full_name, ";") > 0 THEN
    SET @rs = BuildRowsetFromString(@full_name,';')
    SET @first_name = Field(Row(@rs,1),1)
    SET @last_name = Field(Row(@rs,2),1)
ENDIF

]%%

First Name: %%=v(@first_name)=%%
Last Name: %%=v(@last_name)=%%
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!